# 2007 MKZ Engine Won't Turn

Tags: battery

The engine turn has been "weak" the last week or so. This morning it was kinda cold and it wouldn't turn at all; I'd hear a slight buzzing sound and the dash lights would kind of flicker when the ignition was turned. Without performing any troubleshooting at all I got a jump and the engine turned over without issue. Do you think it's just a bad battery?

Comment: My first guess will be the battery, and since it's likely the original one then 6 years seems fair for a battery life.

Comment: I just a similar situation with my (totally different) car.  Once I had the car started, I went straight to the store to get a new battery.  It's just not worth wasting your time: if you can't remember when you bought this battery, it's probably out of warranty so it's worthy of replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Check and test the battery as it's likely to be the problem. If it tests okay and is fully charged, the next likely culprit will be the starter motor solenoid. Assuming the battery is all good, remove the starter motor and have the brushes checked/replaced by a local business who do electrical repairs.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably just a bad battery, but make sure to check the terminals and cables for corrosion. Be sure to check the ground cable not only at the battery, but also at the points where it connects to the body and engine/transmission!